# Get the first and the last day of a month from the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
datetime      open      high     low       close    
2006-01-02    4566.95   4601.35  4542.00   4556.25
2006-01-03    4531.45   4605.45  4531.45   4600.25  
2006-01-04    4619.55   4707.60  4616.05   4694.14
.
.
.
```

Need to calculate the Monthly Returns in %

```
Formula: (Month Closing Price - Month Open Price) / Month Open Price
```

I can't seem to get the open price and closing price of a month, because in my df most months dont have a log for the 1st of the month. So having trouble calculating it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `groupby` and `agg` function in order to get the first and last value of each column in each month:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dt.txt")
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df.set_index("datetime", inplace=True)
resultDf = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).agg(["first", "last"])
resultDf["new_column"] = (resultDf[("close", "last")] - resultDf[("open", "first")])/resultDf[("open", "first")]
resultDf.index.rename(["year", "month"], inplace=True)
resultDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
resultDf
```

The code above will result in a dataframe that has multiindex column. So, if you want to get, for example, rows with year of 2010, you can do something like:

```py
resultDf[resultDf["year"] == 2010]
```

Comment: thanks for this, need some more help if you don't mind. Need to filter this df for years after 2010. any clue on how to do it?

Comment: @Pavan Glad to help, Pavan. I'll edit the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom grouper such as follow :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""datetime\topen\thigh\tlow\tclose
2006-01-02\t4566.95\t4601.35\t4542.00\t4556.25
2006-01-03\t4531.45\t4605.45\t4531.45\t4600.25  
2006-01-04\t4619.55\t4707.60\t4616.05\t4694.14""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

dg = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', axis=0, freq='M'))
```

Then each group of dg is separate by month, and since we convert datetime as pandas.datetime we can use classic arithmetic on it :

```
def monthly_return(datetime, close_value, open_value):
    index_start = np.argmin(datetime)
    index_end = np.argmax(datetime)
    return (close_value[index_end] - open_value[index_start]) / open_value[index_start]

dg.apply(lambda x : monthly_return(x.datetime, x.close, x.open))
Out[97]: 
datetime
2006-01-31    0.02785
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Of course a pure functional approach is possible instead of using `monthly_return` function